# Проблема с обновлением колонки в таблице Hive

Tags: sql, hive

Всем привет.

Есть такая таблица в Hive:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE users
    (
    uid string,
    url string,
    is_auto int,
    is_youngparent int,
    is_pregnant int,
    is_politic int
    )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'path';
```

Далее мне нужно обновить is_auto исходя из условий в url.

Делаю так:

```
UPDATE users
SET is_auto =
    CASE WHEN url == 'cars.ru' OR url == 'avto-russia.ru' OR url == 'bmwclub.ru' THEN is_auto = 1 ELSE is_auto = 0 END;
```

Но выдает ошибку:

org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException:Attempt to do update or delete on table users that is not transactional

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35147685/4496422

Comment: что здесь? я не понял

Comment: кмк `и иметь в ней свойства 'transactional' = 'true'`